# pip._vendor strange behaviour but requests works

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I got issue when running my code. I see following error. The interesting thing is when i take this code to other environment like `visual code` the code is working and i am getting response... I think something is wrong with `from pip._vendor import` requests which `pycharm` adding automatically. For instance in `visual code` is adding `imports requests` and it works. What should i do this code to run correctly in `pycharm`?

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed
 to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000217D0A2B9C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection atte
mpt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
 raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.xxx', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/ser (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vend
or.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000217D0A2B9C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respo
nd after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

This is my code:

```
from pip._vendor import requests


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(msg)

    data = {
        "Ex": 22
        }
    }

    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer xxxx"
    }

    response = requests.post("https://xxx.xxx/api/ser", headers=headers, json=data)

    print(response.json())
```

Comment: If it works via CLI as well, please, pay attention to your firewall/antivirus settings.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the `_vendor` import of your `pip` library. It works, but you can just do `import requests` instead (if it has been already installed).